# List of many dictonaries in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to convert this list of dictionaries to pandas data frame in correct order

```
[{'SET_ID_PATIENT_ID': '1'}, {'PATIENT_ID_EXTERNAL_ID': '53203'}, {'PATIENT_ID_INTERNAL_ID': 'SUF5120411SC'}, {'PATIENT_NAME': 'SCOTT^HAROLD'}, {'DATE_OF_BIRTH': '19340410'}, {'SEX': 'M'}, {'PATIENT_ADDRESS': '20 HURTIN BOULEVARD^^SMITHTOWN^NY^11787'}, {'PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER': '204028637190'}, {'SSN_NUMBER_PATIENT': '090280291'}, {'SET_ID_PATIENT_ID': '1'}, {'PATIENT_ID_EXTERNAL_ID': '103308'}, {'PATIENT_ID_INTERNAL_ID': '97876400400'}, {'PATIENT_NAME': 'WISNISKI^ROBERT'}, {'DATE_OF_BIRTH': '19900119'}, {'SEX': 'M'}, {'PATIENT_ADDRESS': '3 PINEDALE RD^^HAUPPAUGE^NY^11788'}, {'PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER': '202728605261'}, {'SSN_NUMBER_PATIENT': '129761945'}, {'SET_ID_PATIENT_ID': '1'}, {'PATIENT_ID_EXTERNAL_ID': '103308'}, 
'PATIENT_ID_INTERNAL_ID': '97876400400'}, {'PATIENT_NAME': 'WISNISKI^ROBERT'}, {'DATE_OF_BIRTH': '19900119'}, {'SEX': 'M'}, {'PATIENT_ADDRESS': '3 PINEDALE RD^^HAUPPAUGE^NY^11788'}, {'PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER': '202728605260'}, {'SSN_NUMBER_PATIENT': '129761945'},
```

But I am getting the data like this with a new line:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3QB5.png

I do not want my data in a new line

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pandas 

import pandas as pd  #import pandas library

data=[{'SET_ID_PATIENT_ID': '1'}, {'PATIENT_ID_EXTERNAL_ID': 
'53203'}, {'PATIENT_ID_INTERNAL_ID': 'SUF5120411SC'}, 
{'PATIENT_NAME': 'SCOTT^HAROLD'}, {'DATE_OF_BIRTH': '19340410'}, 
{'SEX': 'M'}, {'PATIENT_ADDRESS': '20 HURTIN 
BOULEVARD^^SMITHTOWN^NY^11787'}, {'PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER': 
'204028637190'}, {'SSN_NUMBER_PATIENT': '090280291'}, 
{'SET_ID_PATIENT_ID': '1'}, {'PATIENT_ID_EXTERNAL_ID': '103308'}, 
{'PATIENT_ID_INTERNAL_ID': '97876400400'}, {'PATIENT_NAME': 
'WISNISKI^ROBERT'}, {'DATE_OF_BIRTH': '19900119'}] 

df = pd.DataFrame() # create empty dataframe
for i in data:       #iterate through each value
   df[list(i.keys())[0]]=list(i.values())  #convert dict to dataframe
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).